# Symfony 4 - Multiple forms of same type with dynamic display fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, types

I would like to use my `UserType` form class to register a user and to edit the user profile. As I want to the admins to register a user while setting up their roles, I don't want the user to modify that options. So I would like to use 2 different forms but for the same type `User`.

Can I create 2 different `buildForm()` functions in one `FormType` class ?
Or do I need to create another type ?

Here is my `UserType` class (main purpose was to register a user) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
            ->add('birthdate', BirthdayType::class, array(
                'placeholder' => '-'))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options'  => array('label' => 'password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'repeat-password'),
            ))
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
               'multiple' => true,
               'expanded' => true, // render check-boxes
               'choices' => [
                   'Administrateur' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                   'Direction' => 'ROLE_MANAGER',
                   'Comptabilite' => 'ROLE_ACCOUNTING',
                   'Commercial' => 'ROLE_MARKETING',
                   'Docteur' => 'ROLE_DOCTOR',
                   'Client' => 'ROLE_CLIENT',
               ],
           ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to dynamically add the roles to the formType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->is_admin = $options['is_admin'];
    // [...]
    if ($this->is_admin)
        $builder
           ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
               'multiple' => true,
               'expanded' => true, 
               'choices' => [
                   'Administrateur' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                   'Direction' => 'ROLE_MANAGER',
                   'Comptabilite' => 'ROLE_ACCOUNTING',
                   'Commercial' => 'ROLE_MARKETING',
                   'Docteur' => 'ROLE_DOCTOR',
                   'Client' => 'ROLE_CLIENT',
               ],
           ])
        // [...]
    ;
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        // [...]
        'is_admin' => false,
    ]);
}
```

Then pass the variable like

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, array(
    'is_admin' => $this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'),
);
```

Comment: I use directly `if ($options['is_admin'])` but thanks good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily handle this using `array $options`
in controller set `choices` of roles and add them to `$option`
and in userType do something like this:

```
->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
           'multiple' => true,
           'expanded' => true, // render check-boxes
           'choices' => $options['choices'],
       ])
```